# It doesn't sound right — "...later than 10 minutes before the start"

Tags: grammar

Imagine that you are the owner of a comedy club. You need a plaque that informs potential customers that the tickets can't be bought later than 10 minutes before the start of the show.

Here's my version which doesn't sound right:

> Tickets can't be bought later than 10 minutes before the start of the show.

Please help me change it to be grammatically correct. Also, is it the right place to ask a question like this?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but it's not clear. _Latest_ is confusing when used with _before_; they're both time words, but with different references. Better to say that ticket sales stop ten minutes before the start of the show.

Comment: @JohnLawler, thank you, good sir, it's perfect! I love you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps say: "Tickets can be bought no later than 10 minutes before showtime."